# How do I link the same page in another language with the i18n gem for Refinery CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, refinerycms, i18n-gem

I'm converting a site into the Rails based Refinery CMS, I've setup the [i18n refinery cms gem](https://github.com/parndt/refinerycms-i18n) and I've created multi-lingual versions of my pages. I'd like to create a locale switcher on the page, so that a user can click on a flag and switch between the various languages for the particular page that they are on.

How can I get the available languages for a page, and their respective links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# In a controller
::I18n.locale = params[:locale]
```

---

```
<!-- In a view with a dropdown -->
<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
        <% Refinery::I18n.frontend_locales.each do |frontend_locale| %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to Refinery::I18n.locales[frontend_locale], refinery.url_for(:locale => frontend_locale) %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="laguages">
    <%
    @page.translations.each do |t|
    %> 
        <li>
            <%= link_to "#{@page.translations.find_by_locale(t.locale).title} (#{Refinery::I18n.locales[t.locale]} #{image_tag("/assets/refinery/icons/flags/#{t.locale}.png")})".html_safe, refinery.url_for(:locale => t.locale) %>
        </li>    
    <%
    end
    %>
</ul>
```